# Is there a way to retrieve tweets in a specific trend?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I was wondering if there was a way to retrieve tweets in a specific trend? For example, a trend right now is #AirAsia and therefore, I would like to get, for example, 50 tweets from that trend. I tried looking at tweepy but couldn't find anything except for trends in a certain location.

EDIT

I would like to clarify that I am not looking for a specific hashtag but a trend. For example, as mentioned in the comments, "Greece" is a trend but it is *not* a hashtag. Therefore, a trend is not necessarily a hashtag and vice versa, a hashtag is not necessarily a trend.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19660642/how-to-retrieve-tweets-with-specific-hashtag

Comment: @BenHarold I don't see how this is a duplicate.. A hashtag is not necessarily a trend and vice versa, a trend is not necessarily a hash tag. For example, "Greece" is currently trending where I live but it is _not_ a hashtag.

Comment: Okay, I'm adding an edit to accommodate for that.

Comment: @Downvoter is there a way for me to improve my post? Thanks!

Comment: @JeelShah not the downvoter but excellent clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use Twitter Search:

https://twitter.com/search-home

Or:

2. Google "twitter hashtag airAsia" or go to the address https://twitter.com/hashtag/airasia

You can retrieve as many tweets as you want in any given trend.

Note that method #1 of using Twitter's search engine allows you to search any keyword or trend, which isn't necessarily a hashtag.

3. Similar to the Twitter Search function, the following Search API can be used to find tweets 'containing an exact phrase': [Link to Search API Documentation](http://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I was wondering if there was a way to do this via tweepy or some other twitter python API?

Comment: Oh I see. I'll see if I can add something.

Comment: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search   Is this what you need? Looks like you can find tweets containing an exact phrase. This is, then, similar to the Twitter Search function.

Comment: Ahh I think I can use that in combination with something else. Essentially, twitter provides a tool to find the trends in a specific location, so I can use those trends and then use what you just linked to find the tweets. Thanks! It's perfect! `:D` If you could just add that bit to the answer that would be awesome.

Comment: Okay great. I will do so, then.

Comment: Included it in the answer.